# imagemagick convert pdf with transparency to jpg

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png, jpeg, transparency

When converting a PDF with images with transparency, the output ends up with a black background

```
convert -density 300 -background white -alpha off \
-resize 80x80 -strip -quality 70 file.pdf[0] thumb.jpg[0]
```

Have tried to set the background to white and deactivate alpha, but the background still ends up black!?

Test file

http://www.bluemachines.dk/pdf/trans.pdf

Have tested on these two versions so it looks like a generel "issue"

`ImageMagick-6.8.8-10`

`ImageMagick-6.7.7-10`

## update

```
# /var/bin/ImageMagick-6.8.8-10/utilities/convert
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-10 Q16 x86_64 2014-04-10

 # gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.14 (2014-03-26)
```

Here is the output file

http://www.bluemachines.dk/pdf/thumb.jpg

## -debug ALL

Can't post that much in the body so the output is pasted into this txt file

http://www.bluemachines.dk/pdf/debug.txt

Comment: Sample file would be helpful.

Comment: here you go :) http://www.bluemachines.dk/pdf/trans.pdf

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem with ImageMagick-6.8.9-0.  Perhaps your ghostscript version is causing the problem.  I have version 9.10.  The thumbnail is really small (34 pixels high) so I changed -density 300 to -density 72.  Finally I moved the input filename to the beginning of the commmandline (convert file.pdf[0] ...)

Comment: I was also unable to reproduce the problem.  Tested on a Debian system with Imagemagick 6.7.7 and Ghostscript 9.05.

Comment: Works as expected with ImageMagick-6.8.8 & Ghostscript 9.10. Can you run your example with `-debug All` option, and post it?

Comment: Have updated my question.. Ghostscript is version `9.14`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use *-alpha remove* instead of *-alpha off*. And I would advise you to change the order of your arguments to this:

```
convert -density 300 file.pdf[0] -resize 80x80 -background white -alpha remove \
-strip -quality 70 thumb.jpg
```